# Sharepoint central not opening

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Please let me know where to locate this file to make the necessary changes ?

Edit applicationHost.config:

Regards

Comment: have u check in `inetmgr`(IIS Server)? Central Administration's Application pool is running or not?

Comment: Yes, Application pool is running. But I think now I am not getting the response from IIS when I type HTTP://localhost. no idea what to do? please help

Comment: when u open inetmgr.its working propertly? means have u got error related to applicationhost.config?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid typing in localhost as that is most likely not configured as a host header for the Central Administration web application.  Also in almost every environment Central Administration is configured to run on a custom port.  I do not see a custom port in your original post.  Use start, programs, SharePoint 2010, Central Administration.  This should bring up IE with the correct address.  If this comes up with http://localhost then check in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and see what IP address localhost is mapped to.  It should be 127.0.0.1.  Most likely localhost is not the correct name.  You can also look in IIS Manager and view the bindings for the Central Admin site and see what the custom port should be.

It shouldn't be localhost and it will most likely be on a custom port.  So it should look like http://CAServer:32154.  However using the start menu should get you to the right place.